Trapezoidal shape of signals in BLDC motors
One important fact that I did not yet understand in BLDC motor is the trapezoidal shape the driving voltage!! I go through an application note frome microchip:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU16/ApplicationNotes/ApplicationNotes/AN1160-Sensorless-BLDC-Control-with-Back-EMF-Filtering-Using-a-Majority-Function-DS00001160.pdf

The commutation is done with switching transistors (they are either ON of OFF, 1 or 0), so I expect the graph to be square waves and not trapezoidal.
Could anyone explain to me from witch fact the slops, when switching from high to low or low to high come from?
What do we mean by electrical sectors (angles) and how they are connected to time domaine?

Only two phases are driven at one time, the third phase is "Hi-Z" or "Off". You will also notice that only one change is made between each "sector" (as named in your image). The numbered arrows indicate where current flows for each state.



#
High
Low
Hi-Z




1
Blue
Green
Red


2
Blue
Red
Green


3
Green
Red
Blue


4
Green
Blue
Red


5
Red
Blue
Green


6
Red
Green
Blue



The diagonal lines are indicative of the "Back-EMF" - this signal is from the Hi-Z phase, and is often used to determine the commutation timing in sensorless applications.

Could anyone explain to me from witch fact the slops, when switching from high to low or low to high come from

As above, a given phase follows the High -> High -> Hi-Z -> Low -> Low -> Hi-Z sequence, so there is never a direct transition from High to Low. Instead it "feels" the permanent magnet going past, and this induces the observed slope in the winding.

What do we mean by electrical sectors (angles) and how they are connected to time domaine?

The sectors marked on your image align with the table I've shown above - each sector is the same duration, and the transition from one to the next must be carefully timed to ensure the motor spins and doesn't stall. Each sector is 60­° of the full electrical rotation ... 6 x 60° = 360°. The electric rotational speed (i.e: frequency, Hz) is directly correlated with the motor's phyiscal rotational speed (i.e: RPM).

In reality, be aware of two things:

The "perfect" input signal for a given motor can be generated by physically rotating the motor, and is typically a sine wave with a 120° phase shift between each signal.
The output of such an Electronic Speed Controller will generally not be 100% duty cycle (as shown), but will have some PWM component superimposed - this may affect some or all of the signals, making them quite noisy to observe.


In some controllers when a BLDC is driven at partial power the "on" periods simply shrink instead of having PWM superimposed.

Intriguing, I've not seen that control scheme before.

well, it is still pwm, just synchronous

The trapezoid shape refers to the back EMF, not the driving voltage.
In your photo, the blue phase is driven "high" to VDC; the green phase is driven "low" to 0V, and the red phase is not driven at all, and you can observe the trapezoidal shape of its back EMF.
That's how this "sensorless" motor control works, two phases are driven and third is sensed.
